# Complex Expression Tree with no changing context of param

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

i need to  dinamically generate expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> expr = x => (x.SomeField.CompareTo(someValue) <= 0);
```

trying to do it like this:

```
var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "x");
Expression<Func<MyClass, FieldType>> pathToField = x => x.SomeField;
Expression path = pathToField;
if (!(path is LambdaExpression lambdaMember))
    throw ...;
Expression valueExpr = Expression.Constant(someValue);
var bodyExpr = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Expression.Call(lambdaMember.Body, "CompareTo", null, valueExpr ), Expression.Constant(0));
return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, FieldType>>(bodyExpr, paramExpr);
```

but always getting  error when trying to compile this:

> variable 'x' of type 'MyClass' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

how i could do this correctly?

Comment: That doesn't compile. The `var bodyExpr ` has a trailing `},`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using `lambdaMember.Body`, which references the `x` from `x => x.SomeField` - but because you *only* used the `.Body`, that is undefined - and is unrelated to the `x` from `Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "x");`

In the general case, there are 2 options here:

- invoke the **entire** lambda (i.e. `lambdaMember`, not `lambdaMember.Body`) - passing in the *arguments* to use for the parameters
- rewrite the inner lambda at runtime using [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.7.2) - swapping out instances of the `x` from the *inner* expression with whatever you wanted to use as the argument - presumably `paramExpr`

The first option is easier, and is just `Expression.Invoke`:

```
var bodyExpr = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
    Expression.Call(Expression.Invoke(lambdaMember, paramExpr),
    "CompareTo", null, valueExpr), Expression.Constant(0));
```

Note: there *is* a third option in this case, since it is a relatively simple example - you can just hijack the parameter from the *inner* expression and use it *instead of* declaring `paramExpr` as a new parameter expression:

```
var paramExpr = lambdaMember.Parameters.Single();
Expression valueExpr = Expression.Constant(someValue);
var bodyExpr = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
    Expression.Call(lambdaMember.Body,
    "CompareTo", null, valueExpr), Expression.Constant(0));
return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, FieldType>>(bodyExpr, lambdaMember.Parameters);
```

Comment: Thank you, but in third option u just get
`x => x.Field.CompareTo(value)`,
not
`x => x.Field.CompareTo(value) <= 0`

Comment: @RazorRevenant no, you don't; I think you've made a transcription error from the example I gave